# Android Extendedcalendarview Resource Not Found Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, import, calendarview

after importing the extended calendar view for android into my android project, the xml file for my activity does not seem to load the extendedcalendarview into design view of my activity. After looking around, I found out that maybe I might have made a mistake importing the project, but I dont think that is the issue, as I believe I followed all of the correct steps. Here is the error:

Rendering Problems-

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE

Stack Trace:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:626)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:108)
>       at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:2744)
>       at com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView.init(ExtendedCalendarView.java:92)
>       at com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView.(ExtendedCalendarView.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:170)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:197)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:879)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:831)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>       at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>       at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

If anyone can help me out that would be great, and if you need any more info about said error, just leave a comment. Thanks so much!

Comment: I basically ditched extendedcalendarview and am using google calendar api to create calendar events and am using an intent for calendar app to view dates of such events.